# $c$-theorem explicit examples

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions

To give background, the $c$-theorem applies to 2D QFT's and the function form is given as $c(g) = C(g) + 4H + 6G$ where $C$, $H$ and $G$ are two point functions of the stress energy tensor.

So, I know how to prove the $c$-theorem very well, but I haven't been able to find any concrete examples of computing the $c$-function for a specific field theory. For example, what would the $c$-function look like for, lets say, the Gross-Neveu model of 2D fermions? Really I am wondering if anyone knows about very concrete examples of computing $c(g)$.